# Unable to run shell script on system start on mac?

Tags: macos, launch, launchctl

I want to run a shell script on mac startup. For that i have created a shell script and plist file. I have copied the plist to  `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.exampld.plist`. It has all required permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>Label</key>
   <string>com.example.exampld</string>
   <key>ProgramArguments</key>
   <array><string>/Users/dhiraj/.mydir/startup.sh</string></array>
   <key>RunAtLoad</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have loaded it using below commond

```
sudo launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.exampld.plist
```

And also tested using

```
sudo launchctl start ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.exampld.plist
```

But the shell script code is not executed i can say this because my shell script start a go build and open browser as below but nothing happens.

```
echo #start up go build#

    $HOME/.mydir/./go
    open http://localhost/sample/index.html
```

Comment: You haven't set a `Program` key so how will it know what to run? http://www.launchd.info

Answer (score 0):

`sudo launchctl load` loads launchd agents/daemons in the **local** domain (`/Library/..`).

In the **user** domain you have to call `launchctl` without `sudo`